# Creating New Column with value of other columns based on condition on a third Column in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, mapping

My dataframe looks like this

```
category value1 value2 
A.       20.      30.
B.       40.      50.
A.       60.      70. 
B.       80.      90.
C.       10.      10. 
D.       20.      20.
```

I want to create a new column that has the value of either `value1` or `value2` based on a condition relative to `category`.
For example, if `category` is `A` then store `value1`, if `category` is `B` then store `value2`,if `else` then store `nan`. I expect an output like this:

```
category value1 value2 new_col
A.       20.      30.   20.
B.       40.      50.   50.
A.       60.      70.   60.  
B.       80.      90.   90.
C.       10.      10.   nan
D.       20.      20.   nan
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
# np.select and define list of condition with corresponding values
df['value3']=(np.select([df['category'].eq('A.'), # condition #1
                         df['category'].eq('B.')],# condition #2
                        [df['value1'],            # value when #1 is true
                         df['value2']],           # value when #2 is true
                        np.nan))                  # default value
df
```

```
    category    value1  value2  value3
0          A.   20.0    30.0    20.0
1          B.   40.0    50.0    50.0
2          A.   60.0    70.0    60.0
3          B.   80.0    90.0    90.0
4          C.   10.0    10.0    NaN
5          D.   20.0    20.0    NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, based on [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['new_col'] = np.where(df.category.eq('A.'), df.value1, np.where(
    df.category.eq('B.'), df.value2, np.nan))
```

Output:

```
  category  value1  value2  new_col
0       A.    20.0    30.0     20.0
1       B.    40.0    50.0     50.0
2       A.    60.0    70.0     60.0
3       B.    80.0    90.0     90.0
4       C.    10.0    10.0      NaN
5       D.    20.0    20.0      NaN
```

---

Yet another possible solution, based on [`pandas.DataFrame.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
df['new_col'] = df.value1.loc[df.category.eq('A.')]
df['new_col'].update(df.value2.loc[df.category.eq('B.')])
```

Output:

```
# same
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is with [case_when](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.case_when.case_when) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

(df
.case_when(
    df.category.eq('A.'), df.value1, # condition, result
    df.category.eq('B.'), df.value2,  
    np.nan, # default
    column_name = 'new_col')
)

  category  value1  value2  new_col
0       A.    20.0    30.0     20.0
1       B.    40.0    50.0     50.0
2       A.    60.0    70.0     60.0
3       B.    80.0    90.0     90.0
4       C.    10.0    10.0      NaN
5       D.    20.0    20.0      NaN
```